# Changing the colour of text within a nav element when images don't support the typography

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a full page carousel which has images in. Some images are ok to include within the `<nav>` element and some aren't, due to legibility issues.

For example, image one will take black text but image three needs white text.

I don't have any code as my junior developer is trying to work on the problem but would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can set some additional `data` attributes, ie. `data-img-color` for each of the slides and set image caption's `style="color:":` attribute on each carousel's slide, to the one provided in `data-img-color`.